# How to manually change line size and alpha values for ggplot2 lines (separated by factor)?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to create a graph where I can change the line size for each line `c(1,2,3)` and the alpha values for each line `c(0.5,0.6,0.7)`. I tried to use scale_size_manual but it didn't make any difference. Any ideas on how to proceed?

```
var <- c("T","T","T","M","M","M","A","A","A")
val <- rnorm(12,4,5)
x <- c(1:12)

df <- data.frame(var,val,x)

ggplot(aes(x= x , y = val, color = var, group = var), data = df)  +
scale_color_manual(values = c("grey","blue","black")) +  geom_smooth(aes(x = x, y = val), formula = "y ~ x", method = "loess",se = FALSE, size = 1) + scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(1, 12, 1), limits=c(1, 12)) + scale_size_manual(values = c(1,2,3))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set the `size` and `alpha` values for your lines you have to map on aesthetics. Otherwise `scale_size_manual` will have no effect:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(aes(x = x, y = val, color = var, group = var), data = df) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("grey", "blue", "black")) +
  geom_smooth(aes(x = x, y = val, size = var, alpha = var), formula = "y ~ x", method = "loess", se = FALSE) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(1, 12, 1), limits = c(1, 12)) +
  scale_size_manual(values = c(1, 2, 3)) +
  scale_alpha_manual(values = c(.5, .6, .7))
```

[image]